# Delete a Subversion branch in Netbeans on MAC 10.8.5

Tags: svn, netbeans, branching-and-merging

I've created a wrong branch in my Subversion repository. 
I work with Netbeans 8.0.2 and its Subversion plugin on MAC OS 10.8.5.

I don't want to keep this branch, so how can I delete it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this NetBeans issue (bug 137072)](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=137072) NetBeans does not have a repository browser. Therefore, you should use an external Subversion client for this task (i.e. not the one built-in to NetBeans IDE).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do you know any user friendly solution to do this on Mac 10.8.5 ?

Comment: @scii there are various Subversion clients for OSX but most of them are outdated as far as I recall. Search the web. However, I can suggest trying SmartSVN, Versions, Cornerstone or SynchroSVN.